# LLVM IR directly to a shared binary file (without any intermediate files)

Tags: llvm-ir, lld

I'm wondering if there is a way to go directly from LLVM IR (contained in a cpp program, i.e. in memory) to a shared binary? I'm looking for a way that does not create any intermediate files on disk except the end result, i.e. the shared binary. Is this possible? If yes, where can I find documentation / references on how to do it? Thanks!